# CakePHP Help with Blog Tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp

I've just been following the tutorial on the CakePHP website to create a simple Blog as a way to learn a bit about Cake. However I have run into an error and not sure why as I have followed exactly what the tutorial says. The errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Html [APP/views/posts/index.ctp, line 17]
Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/dentist/app/views/posts/index.ctp on line 17
```

Here is my posts_controller

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $name = 'Posts';

    function index() {
         $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    function view($id = null) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
    }
}
?>
```

and here is my model

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
}

?>
```

and here are my views

```
<!-- File: /app/views/posts/index.ctp -->

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

**Update**

Turns out I was using an older version of CakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://book.cakephp.org/view/1572/New-features-in-CakePHP-1-3:

> Helpers can now be addressed at
>   $this->Helper->func() in addition to
>   $helper->func(). This allows view
>   variables and helpers to share names
>   and not create collisions.

You're using a version of CakePHP below 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line in your view,

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
```

use this to call the helpers:

```
<?php echo $html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
```

Comment: I guess you are using an old cakephp version.

Comment: I had the very same trouble and *am* using Cake 1.3.0.0. but yvoyer's suggestion worked.